# name 'QPrinter' is not defined

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm learning how to use Python on Qgis. I'm using the 'Therminal Python' and my Qgis is the 2.16.3, 64 bits.

I loaded layers from Postgis. I'm trying to generate a PDF. I use the code on the chapter 9 on PyQGIS developer cookbook. Basically 'copy and paste'.

The class QPrinter() is not recognized. Then, the rest of the code has problem.

Note that I included 'import"'s as I read in many solutions on this forum. What I must to do?

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
printer = QPrinter()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'QPrinter' is not defined"
```

Comment: Most welcome, already posted the comment as an answer for the convenience of others =)

Answer (score 2):

You need to import `QPrinter` with the following:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPrinter
```

Answer (score 0):

You be able to import QPrinter with the following:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter
```